# Decrement/Subtraction of number in string in EJS

Tags: node.js, math, ejs, decrement

I have this line in EJS file:

`<%= nominations[i].month %>`

I want to decrement it in the EJS by 1. 
So I tried:

`<%= (nominations[i--].month) %>`

But this didn't change the output value.

I tried subtraction also but the output still stayed the same.

`<%= (nominations[i-1].month) %>`

I also tried:

`<%= (nominations[i].month -1) %>`

Update: I didn't realize the number is in string format, the solution:

Comment: if you want to get an answer to your question you have to provide the data samples for the `nominations` object from your examples, your examples are incomplete

Comment: Hi @micnic, I don't want to do decrement/substraction in the database, I want it to only be displayed in the view.

Comment: as I wrote before, it is not clear what is the structure of your data and what you are trying to subtract, none can help you if you do not provide an example of the `nominations` object

Comment: Hi, in  "<%= nominations[i].month %>"  nominations is name of the table, and month is column name, month is integer and currenly  displays: 9,  and I want to decrement/substract it by 1 so it equals to 8 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution in case it help someone else in future.
I didn't realize that nominations[i].month is actually string data type.
I manage to subtract the number by 1.

First converted the string to the number

`<%= parseInt(nominations[i].month) %>`

And then I subtract by 1

`<%= parseInt(nominations[i].month-1) %>`